# В предложении ошибок нет?

Tags: стилистическая-ошибка

На территории республики граждан, пострадавших от действий недобросовестных застройщиков при долевом строительстве жилых домов, не имеется, практики разрешения проблем таких граждан отсутствует.

Answer (score 2):

В предложении ошибки **есть**:
1) "практик**и**... отсутствует" (нужно "практик**а**");
2) странно жаловаться на отсутствие практики в отношении граждан, которых *нет*.
Поэтому лучше ограничиться первым утверждением:

> На территории республики **нет** граждан, пострадавших от действий
>   недобросовестных застройщиков при долевом строительстве жилых домов.
>   (В любом случае практика разрешения проблем таких граждан
>   отсутствует.)

Ещё формально может возникнуть вопрос: откуда известно, что на *территорию* не заехали граждане той же республики, но пострадавшие в других местах? Поэтому проще сказать "в республике" (это подразумевает проживающих в ней граждан).

Answer (score 1):

Если строго подходить к смыслу, то вот вариант:

**Граждан, пострадавших от действий недобросовестных застройщиков при долевом строительстве жилых домов на территории республики, не установлено. Практика разрешения таких проблем отсутствует.**

- Здесь ясно сказано, что речь идет о строительстве на территории республики.
- Корректней не заявлять, что нет, а употреблять выражения "не установлено", "не зарегистрировано", "не выявлено".
- Сказано "разрешения таких проблем", что корректней, чем "разрешения проблем таких граждан".
- Для лучшего восприятия предложение разбито на два.